# Sharepoint Online basic document library approval Workflow best practices?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, microsoft-flow

I'm learning about Sharepoint for a while but something still confusing me. What I need is really basic one person approval workflow for a document library (later four approval). After tons of research, I found there are basically three ways how to create it (maybe even more) -

1. Approval - Sharepoint 2010 workflow template (**from document library setting** right at the page)
2. Approval - Sharepoint 2010 workflow (**from scratch using Sharepoint Designer 2013**)
3. Microsoft Flow - for me there is big issue with "choice" field because it's read only and I want to let users to approve document via e-mail button or go to the SharePoint portal and approve it by "hand" if there are more things to approve and with that they must write to a "text" field word "approved" which is annoying.

What are the "best" practices to create that basic Workflow? I found most of tutorials for the 1. option but I have a problem with that because I don't have "Approval - Sharepoint 2010" template even if I activate site function - Workflow Task Content Type and I'm site contributor. Thanks you so much for the answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is basic one person workflow you can start with "Approval - SharePoint 2010" workflow in SharePoint online.

To get this workflow you need to activate a site collection feature.

- Login to site with Site Collection admin rights.
- Go to Site settings - Site collection features
- Search for feature "Workflow" and activate.
- It will provide bunch of out-of-box workflows.

[image]

Comment: Thanks it helps. So now I'm using 2010 approval for documents and flow with modern lists for vacation approval.

Comment: Please mark as answer if it helpful.